# Fullcalendar: Disable default dayClick functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to disable Fullcalendar's default functionality when you click on a day (in agendaWeek view).  If I leave dayClick: out entirely, it still pops up a dialog asking for an event name, and whether you enter one or hit Cancel, it still adds an event.  I'd rather it did nothing at all.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to create an example? I can't reproduce any default behavior for [`dayClick`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/). [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xo8qwkx4/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33937947/5494359). You have to change the test to the view you want. Something like this.

```
if($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').type != 'agendaWeek') {

}
```