# FullCalendar - prompt on dayClick only in certain views

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In FullCalendar, is there a way to avoid opening a event insertion prompt when I click on a day in monthView? What I want to do is a changeview and go to the clicked date, which is working, but the prompt is still opening.

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){
    //This works fine, but open a prompt to add new event
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('changeView','agendaWeek');
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate',date);
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? According with documentation, that you are saying is not possible.  If you look at this example: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/ you can view an example to change background, without more functionality.

Comment: Actually are possible, using the solution below. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, you are showing prompt in "select" event callback.

If you want to handle "select" event for day/week view and not for month view, you can check the current view and act accordingly.

Ex.

```
if($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').type != 'month') {
}
```